# Sign out current logged in User with AddAuthentication()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to log a user out of it's session. Right now it doesn't sign the user out at all..
It has been running throughout the weekend and when I went back to the website, it instantly logged me back in and I dont know what is causing this to last so long.

I want the current logged user to be signed out after 30 minutes if nothing has happened on the webpage.

This is my Startup.cs I have added services.AddAuthentication(), services.AddSession(), App.UseSession() and App.UseCookiePolicy.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Opticool.Data;
using Opticool.models.optcool;
using Opticool.Models;
using Opticool.Models.optcool;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Opticool
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection");
            services.AddDbContext<optcoolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Xw>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //When the browser closes it automatically deletes session based cookies (non-persistent cookies),
            //but no cookies are cleared when an individual tab is closed. The server is not notified of tab or browser close events.
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                options.Cookie.Name = "Auth.cookie";

                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            });

            //services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            //{ 
            //    options.Cookie.Name = "Forge.cookie";
            //    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            //    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            //});

            services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie-tmp");
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName($"my-app-{Environment.EnvironmentName}")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($@"{Environment.ContentRootPath}\keys"));


            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-._@+ ";
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<Xw> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Container/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();
            //AdminSeed.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed the following in my Login.cshtml.cs (Razor Page) that logs the user in on the webpage.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Opticool.Models.optcool;
using Opticool.models.optcool;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            var claim = new List<Claim>
                {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name),
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claim, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var authproperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = false,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15),
                RedirectUri = returnUrl

            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using var OptContext = new optcoolContext();

                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                //Input.UserName is actually input.Xw.Relatienummer --> check in Register.cshtml.cs
                if (Context.Dr.Where(x => x.CompanyNr== Convert.ToInt32(Input.UserName)).Count() > 0 || 
                    Input.UserName.Contains("Admin") && Input.Password.Contains("Admin"))
                {
                    var result = await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authproperties);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), RedirectUri = "/Home/Index" };
                        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Currently the
`var result = await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authproperties);` will give me an error "Cannot assign void to an implcitly-typed variable." While when using _signinManager.SignInPasswordAsync(Name, Password, RememberMe, False) works normal because it is standard scaffolded code.

To sum up my problem:
My User won't be signed out of it's Session. no matter the time. I want the User to be signed out after 30 minutes of being Idle on the website.

I have followed [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.0) but I can't find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to use F12 developer tools to check the cookie, perhaps the browser stores the old cookie and the cookie are session based.

OP F12 developer tools -> Application -> right click current site, and click clear option.

[image]

Besides, to set the cookie expiration, we have to set the `IsPersistent` to true in AuthenticationProperties. Code like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    });
```

Or

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        //When ExpiresUtc is set, it overrides the value of the ExpireTimeSpan option of CookieAuthenticationOptions, if set.
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20) 
    });
```

Then, we can see the cookie expire time via F12 developer tool:

[image]

For more information, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [view the sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples).

Comment: You're a life safer mate. I cannot thank you enough for showing me in this much detail!